# Find the equation of the plane which bisects the pair of planes $2x-3y+6z+2=0$ and $2x+y-2z=4$ at acute angles.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-curves, solid-geometry

> Find the equation of the plane which bisects the pair of planes $2x-3y+6z+2=0$ and $2x+y-2z=4$ at acute angles.

**My try**:

The normal to the plane  $2x-3y+6z+2=0$ has direction ratios $2,-3,6$ and the normal to the plane $2x+y-2z=4$ has direction ratios $2,1,-2$.

Hence the angle between them is $\cos \theta=\vert\dfrac{n_1.n_2}{|n_1||n_2|}\vert=\dfrac{11}{45}$.

How to find the equation of the required plane from here?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y,z)$ be a point in the needed plane.

Thus, $$\frac{|2x-3y+6z+2|}{\sqrt{2^2+(-3)^2+6^2}}=\frac{|2x+y-2z-4|}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2+(-2)^2}},$$
which gives equations of two our planes.

I got
$$x+2y-4z-\frac{17}{4}=0;$$
$$10x-y+2z-11=0.$$

Now, take $A(1,1,1)$, which is placed on the second plane.

Let $AB$ be a perpendicular from $A$ to the plane $2x+y-2z-4=0$ (easy to see that $AB=1$) and $AC$ be a perpendicular from $A$ to the intersection line of  given planes.

If $\measuredangle ACB<45^{\circ}$ then $10x-y+2z-11=0$ is the answer.

While if $\measuredangle ACB>45^{\circ}$ then $x+2y-4z-\frac{17}{4}=0$ is the answer.

Comment: Why have you set distance of a point from two planes equal?

Comment: It follows from triangles congruence. Draw it!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: The vector $\|\mathbf b\|\mathbf a + \|\mathbf a\|\mathbf b$ bisects the angle between $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$.

**EDIT**: We need to compare the angle between $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ and the angle between $\mathbf a$ and $-\mathbf b$. One will be acute and one will be obtuse, and they want us to choose the one that is *acute* to bisect. As it turns out, the former is a bit more than $121^\circ$ and the latter is a bit less than $59^\circ$. So we should work with the latter.

(Note that $(2,-3,6)\cdot (2,1,-2) < 0$ whereas $(2,-3,6)\cdot (-2,-1,2)>0$.)

Comment: So if I take $a=n_1,b=n_2\implies ||b||a+||a||b=(20,-2,4)$ then how to find equation of the required plane

Comment: You need a point on both planes, and then the plane through this point with the normal vector you've computed.

Comment: How can I find a point which lies in the intersection of both the planes

Comment: Try setting one of the coordinates equal to $0$ and solving for the other two.

Comment: I got the point to be $(\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},0)$ and the equation to be $10x-y+2z=11$

Comment: Unfortunately the answer does not match

Comment: See my edit. We need to consider the angle between the original normal vectors and make sure it's acute, not obtuse.